# Smooth function $y$ that satisfies $dy|_p=w$ for covector $w$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, co-tangent-space

If $M$ is a smooth manifold, $w\in T^*_pM$, then is it possible to find a smooth function $y:M\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $dy|_p=w$. If it is, is there an easy way to give $y$ explicitly? I have just learned about covectors and I am not really understanding them overly well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Start by solving this in $\Bbb R^n$ with $p=0$. Can you write down a function $f$ with $df|_0 = \sum a_i\,dx^i$ (here the $a_i$ are constants)?

Comment: So do we want to find a function $f$ that satisfies $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(0)=a_i$ for each $i$?

Comment: Yes! Precisely. Then you will need to think what to do away from the origin so that you'll be able to put this on $M$ and get a smooth function defined everywhere. :)

Comment: I am confused how to then pull back to $M$ after doing so. Do I use any local coordinate of $p$?

Comment: Yes, you use a chart that sends $p$ to $0$. That will give you a smooth function in a neighborhood of $p$. Now you have to think about my further comment.

Comment: So can I just find a function $f$ that satisfies this in $\overline{B_r(0)}$. So say $f=\sum_i a_ix^i$ in this ball, then I can extend $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ to some $h$ such that $h|_{\overline{B_r(0)}}=f$ and $h$ is supported in $B_{2r}(0)$? Would that work? Here I choose $r$ so that $B_{2r}(0)$ is contained in $\phi(U)$ where $(U,\phi)$ is the local chart in question

Comment: Perfect, @Adam.